# Change title of mp3 in id3 tags to the file name

Tags: macos, tags, mp3, id3

I have hundreds of mp3 files that have unique file names in succession.  i.e. mysong8001.mp3 and mysong8002.mp3 and mysong8101.mp3 where "80" and "81" are the year and "01" and "02" reflect the order of the files for a given year.

The person that created the files did not add any tags except for a Title.  Unfortunately all of the files for 1980 have the Title "1980" and all of 1981 have the Title "1981". Once imported into iTunes, there is no way to distinguish the files or their order.

Is there a way to change the id3 tag info for the Title to be the same as the file name? So that in iTunes, the Title would be "mysong8001"?  I would prefer to change this for all files in a directory rather than me having to open each file's info and manually change it.  That would take days to weeks to accomplish.

One other thing that would be nice is that as a group of files, that I could also change other tags as well that would be common to all of them like the "Artist", "Album", etc.

Any suggestion for an app (on a Mac) that would let me do this would be appreciated.

Linda

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be migrated on different StackExchange platform: https://apple.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This one works perfectly.

http://macupdate.com/info.php/id/15407/tritag

Linda

Comment: unfortunately that's a broken link for me :(

Answer (score 0):

I think Mp3Tag ( http://www.mp3tag.de/en/ ) should work fine for you. You can describe a pattern the filename is constructed of and add/remove/change tags to the mp3 file.

Comment: It looks like that is only for Windows and not for a Mac.

Comment: mp3tag is the way all music tagging programs should be written - it's superb!

Answer (score 0):

Life hacker has put together an article on six best id3 tag editors, you might like one of them.

- http://lifehacker.com/5266613/six-best-mp3-tagging-tools

The editors for mac listed are:

1. TuneUp : http://www.tuneupmedia.com/
2. MusicBrainz Picard: http://musicbrainz.org/doc/PicardTagger

Another mac software worth looking is

- http://www.apple.com/downloads/macosx/ipod_itunes/tune%E2%80%A2instructor.html